# How to find coordinates of points lying on circumference of the circle in 3D space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Imagine I have two points in 3D space: A (x0, y0, z0) and B (x, y, z). I can draw a line through them. Now what I want is to take a plane that is orthogonal to the line and contains the point A. Let's say point A is a center of a circle that lies in the plane with some radius r. Now, how do I calculate the coordinates of the points that lie on circumference of this circle?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be infinite points which lie on the perimeter of the circle. The easiest way to represent a circle in $3D$ would be to take the intersection of a sphere and a plane.

Equation of the sphere would be -
$$S : (X-x_o)^2 + (Y-y_o)^2+ (Z-z_o)^2=(x-x_o)^2 + (y-y_o)^2+ (z-z_o)^2$$

Equation of the plane will be - 
$$P : (x-x_o)(X-x_0) + (y-y_o)(Y-y_0)+ (z-z_o)(Z-z_0) =0 $$

The solutions of these two equations will lie on the circumference of the circle.

Comment: thanks, but I am confused still. Imagine I have now an equation of a circle that lies on this plane; it has origin and I know its coordinates; and I have a radius. How do I know coordinates of a point that lies on circle circumference given some angle? I want to do something similar to this idea, but in 3d case given a plane: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839899/how-do-i-calculate-a-point-on-a-circle-s-circumference